# Python 3.5.0 - TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't make this to work.

I've tried:

```
print('Names choosed was %s' % (random.sample(namesList, float(len(namesList))*0.25))), but still doesn't work.
```

Tried to seek other solutions, but still can't solve this.

```
import random

f= open('file.txt','r')
namesList = []

for line in f:
    namesList.append(line.strip())

print('There are %d names in list and we will choose %.0f from the list.' % (len(namesList), float(len(namesList))*0.25))

print('Names choosed was %s' % (random.sample(namesList, len(namesList)*0.25)))

f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point is the devil, just divide:

```
print('Names choosed was %s' % (random.sample(namesList, len(namesList) // 4),))
```

If you need to convert from a non-fixed `float` to a rough `int` divisor, one approach would be to divide `1` by the `float` to get the inverse, then convert to `int` (with `int` constructor, or `round` or whatever you like), e.g.:

```
divisor = int(1 / floatval)
print('Names choosed was %s' % (random.sample(namesList, len(namesList) // divisor),))
```

Comment: Wow, that's works! Can I ask you something? Why use //4 instead of /4? I'm missing something here.

Comment: @RafaelDias: In Python 3, `/` is "true division", which for `int / int` always produces `float` (`1 / 4` -> `0.25`). `//` is "floor division" (`1 // 4` -> `0`). Even on Py2, `//` is always available (to get `/` as "true division", you'd need `from __future__ import division` at the top of the file), so it's a good idea to use it whenever you want floor division.

Comment: thanks for you help! I need so much to learn! Can I ask you something? How to learn more abou python? I've made few beginners courses but for this simple question I just spent hours without knowing where and how to solve.

Comment: Well, for the most basic stuff, there is [the main Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). It does cover some of the basics like this.

Answer (score 0):

In your tenth line you only specify the type of the expression (len(namesList)) as float but the output you want to be converted to a float is (len(namesList))*0.25, so I guees it doesn't give you the right output.

In my opinion it would be : float(len(namesList)*0.25)